# Proportion of women in a population

Tags: algebra-precalculus, statistics

The mean height of women in a large population is 1.671m while the mean height of men in the population is 1.758m. The mean height of all members of the population is 1.712m.

Calculate the percentage of population who are women.

Using the sample mean and let $n_m, n_f$ be the number of males and females in the population. We want to find the proportion of females, i.e. $p = n_f/(n_m+n_f)$. I want to try do this using the sample mean, i.e. $\bar{x}_f = (\sum x_f) / n_f = 1.671$ but I can't seem to find $n_f, n_m$ from the information given.

I know we can solve this by using $1.671p + (1-p)1.758 = 1.712$ and solve for $p$, but I want to try using the sample mean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose, the number of men is $M$ and the number of women is $W$. The sum of the heights of the men is $S_1$ , the sum of the heights of the women is $S_2$. Then, we know

$$\frac{S_1}{M}=1.758$$ $$\frac{S_2}{W}=1.671$$ $$\frac{S_1+S_2}{M+W}=1.712$$

Inserting $S_1=1.758M$ and $S_2=1.671W$ into the last equation gives

$$\frac{1.758M+1.671W}{M+W}=1.712$$

Multiplying with $M+W$ gives $$1.758M+1.671W=1.712M+1.712W$$

which is equivalent to $$0.046M=0.041W$$ and therefore $$\frac{W}{W+M}=\frac{1}{1+\frac{M}{W}}=\frac{1}{1+\frac{0.041}{0.046}}=0.529$$